# how to open an .apk file

Tags: java, android

hi i am a new developer, i created an app of my own. I created the .apk file and get it signed and aligned it. When i was running it on my device i thought of doing some changes in it, but i missed the original source code. Can i get back my source code using the aligned.apk file... I am using eclipse

Comment: Accept answers to some of your previous questions

Comment: Try the steps mentioned in the answer of this [SO][1] question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The apk is just a zip file so you can unzip it. Your code will be in a classes.dex file in the dalvik format. There are some tools you can use to convert it back from [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/), and then decompile the class files using [jad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) but your source code will most likely be imcomplete.